# HTML 5 a Tag not downloading file but open a new page

Tags: html

I am trying to make a downloadable file on my web page with this

```
<a href="http://ir-devtestsvr/4ms/media/e54d5f61-7375-405a-a6af-bb37f2447991.PNG" download>View file here</a>
```

but when I click the element, it just opens a page that views the file but not download the link. How can I do that when I clicked the element it will download the file.

Comment: The `download` attribute only works for same-origin URLs.  Is the file you want to make downloadable hosted on the same protocol, port, and host as the page?  Even something as small as the page or file being served as http and the opposite being served as https will break it.  See more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: @MajorProductions it is now working but when the file is .msg file it fails to download.

Comment: @MajorProductions it is now okay, please post your answer so I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `download` attribute only works for same-origin URLs. Is the file you want to make downloadable hosted on the same protocol, port, and host as the page? Even something as small as the page or file being served as http and the opposite being served as https will break it. See more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy